# Passing selected values into another page in php using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new to Javascript and jquery.I wish to pass multiple selected values of dropdown from one php page to function of another php page.

In my dropdown I have two buttons.'Set' and 'unset'.Set will insert values into DB and Unset Deleting from DB.

Here is my php:(php1.php)

```
    printf( '<h1>Update Capabilities</h1>' );
    printf( '<form action="%s" method="POST" id="capabilityform">', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
    printf( '<span class="subHeading">Capabilities</span>' );

    printf('<select name="selectedCapabilities[]" multiple>');
    foreach ($capabilityList as $i)
    {
       printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $i, $i);
    }
    printf( '</select>' );
    printf( '<input type="hidden" name="hosts" value="%s"/>', implode( ',', $hosts ) );
    printf( '<input id="capabilityHosts" type="hidden" name="sethosts" value="" />' );
    printf( '<input id="setCapabilitiesButton" name="setcapabilities" type="summit" value="Set Capabilities"  disabled="disabled" />' );
    printf( '<input id="unsetCapabilitiesButton" name="unsetcapabilities" type="submit" value="Unset Capabilities"  disabled="disabled" />' );
    printf( '</form>' );
```

Another php page has two functions for set and unset.(php2.php)

```
function setCap($host , $capablities)
{
//....sql query here
}
function unsetCap($host , $capablities)
{
//....sql query here
}
```

if we press setCapabilities button all selected values will go to setcap() and for same as unsetCapabilities.

Could you please help to pass the selected values to the above functions using JS?

Comment: AJAX is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add class name to select option.

```
printf( '<h1>Update Capabilities</h1>' );
        printf( '<form action="%s" method="POST" id="capabilityform">', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        printf( '<span class="subHeading">Capabilities</span>' );

        printf('<select name="selectedCapabilities[]" class="selectedCapabilities" multiple>');
        foreach ($capabilityList as $i)
        {
           printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $i, $i);
        }
        printf( '</select>' );
        printf( '<input type="hidden" name="hosts" value="%s"/>', implode( ',', $hosts ) );
        printf( '<input id="capabilityHosts" type="hidden" name="sethosts" value="" />' );
        printf( '<input id="setCapabilitiesButton" name="setcapabilities" type="summit" value="Set Capabilities"  disabled="disabled" />' );
        printf( '<input id="unsetCapabilitiesButton" name="unsetcapabilities" type="submit" value="Unset Capabilities"  disabled="disabled" />' );
        printf( '</form>' );
```

and then add this javascript code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("select.selectedCapabilities").change(function(){
        var selectedCapabilities = $(".selectedCapabilities option:selected").val();
            //uncomment alert you can check if you getting right data
            //alert(selectedCapabilities);
             $.ajax({
                 url: "php2.php",
                     type: "post",
                     data: {option: $(this).find("option:selected").val()},
                     success: function(data){
                     //this one you need to show some responce from php2 file
                     $("#getservicesdatas").html(data);
                         }   });
         });

      </script>
```